# Chaplin.js Mediator disposed after browser back

Tags: backbone.js, chaplinjs

i'm developping a sample single web-app and i discover Chaplin.js.
I had implemented a simple login form, and create in application.js (as given example) in intiMediator method:

```
Chaplin.mediator.user = new User();
```

and subscribe for login event in loginController to redirect to internal pages when event is catched

```
Chaplin.mediator.subscribe('login', this.test);
```

finally when user submit login form in loginView i'd wrote

`Chaplin.mediator.user.set({"name":this.model.get("name"),"age":this.model.get("age")});
  Chaplin.mediator.publish('login',this.model);`

And all went ok until i click on browser back button to return to login form. When resubmit the form neither mediator.user has an user obj nor the controller has any subscripion.
Has anyone any tips?
Tks

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Chaplin.js docs *"If you want to give local pub/sub functionality to a class, take a look at the [EventBroker](https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin/blob/master/docs/chaplin.event_broker.md)."*

**Adding pub/sub to a class:**

In your `User` class, you can mixin to add pub/sub functionality by using Underscore's `_.extend`:

```
module.exports = class User

  _.extend @prototype, Chaplin.EventBroker

  constructor: (options) ->
    @subscribeEvent 'login', @test
    # ...
```

**Persist data between routes:**

Now, persist data across routes is another story and you can approach that in many ways depending on your needs. For example, you may know that you can persist a `Chaplin.View` and its related data using [Chaplin.Composer](https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin/blob/master/docs/chaplin.composer.md)

Also, you have plenty of useful tools to keep track of the disposal process. For example you have `beforeControllerDispose` event that is emitted before current controller is disposed.

You could subscribe this event to keep some desired data persisted between routes with the help of a static class. For example, subscribe your Controller to the `beforeControllerDispose` event:

```
# in Controller..
@subscribeEvent 'beforeControllerDispose', @beforeDispose
# ...
beforeDispose: ->
  MyStaticClass.user = @user
  # ... you can do some extra cleanup here. 
  # useful for unbinding stuff that you know it will not be garbage collected/disposed
```

And then, use `Chaplin.Controller.beforeAction` method to ensure that your object is available from the very begining. `beforeAction`, as its names indicates, is automatically called by Chaplin before calling the action (`index`, `show`..) of your actual route/endpoint, so you can use it to pre-assign some data:

```
# in Controller..
beforeAction: ->
   @user = MyStaticClass.user
# ...
index: ->
  # @user is available here
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add code in javascript for those that use Chaplin without CoffeeScript?